# windows Azure multiple tenants vs single tenants for a SaaS application

Tags: azure, saas

windows Azure multiple tenants vs single tenants data. Provide me with the pros and cons of the both. Which one i have to choose in a SaaS model application with windows azure SQL as DB.

Comment: I think this is a very broad topic and gets into architecture, scale units, etc. These aspects are not really specific to Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David's comment.  I think the pros and cons of multi vs single tenancy are primarily business related, not technical.  To whit, please give this a look:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/05/19/now-available-windows-azure-isv-business-economics-package.aspx